# How are API calls logged consistently as a specific user?

Tags: api, user, logs, drush

I wrote some extensive scripts that are run through drush. I use the --user= switch in the drush command that supposedly runs the script as that user. The chosen user has a CiviCRM contact ID too named "My Script" and with super-user alike permissions.

When I study in the CiviCRM change log the user who made notes and changes then there seems to be little or no consistency at all:

- Contacts are logged as created / changed by themselves
- Notes are created by Administrator, which is Drupal uid 1 CiviCRM cid 2

How to cause the script and API call changes to be consistently logged as a specific user? I don't want the logs to be lying and I want it to be identifiable that it was actually "My Script" doing this.